# Get the id of th with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this table:

```
  <th id="a" width="250">Backlog</th>
  <th id="b" width="250">Wip</th>
  <th id="c" width="250">Testing</th> 
  <th id="d" width="250">DOD</th>
</tr>
```

My requirement
[image]

I have 4 columns backlog, WIP, Testing, DOD. If I drag from Backlog to Testing I want to get drop columns id. Ie. i want to save it to database. I tried this:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper",
    scroll: false,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      // Show dropped position.
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
      alert(trid);
      var Stoppos = $(this).position();
      model = {
        id: id,
        left: Stoppos.left,
        top: Stoppos.top
      };

      $.ajax({
        url: "/scrum/save",
        type: "post",
        data: model,
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery.HP({
            title: "Success!",
            message: "Saved..."
          });
        },
        error: function() {
          //  alert('error is saving');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I tried this to get id of current column, but it didn't work.

```
var trid = $(this).closest('th').attr('id'); alert(trid);
```

How can I get dropped id?

Comment: What is `this` a reference to?

Comment: sorry if made any mistake..don't know jquery well.i think its table@RoryMcCrossan

Comment: If you show us a more complete sample of your JS we can determine what's happening.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have update my question.please help me

Comment: doesn't look like you drop it in the th so getting the closest th will not work

Answer (score 0):

If you clicked the `<th>` then you should get the id via the following line:

```
var id=$(event.target).attr('id');
```

(In case you click on an element withint an element that contains the event, use "currentTarget", instead of "target").

If you click on something else, then you need to navigate there via Parent()/Child() or other measures. Do you have the HTML? And which element if HTML is returned when using $(event.target) ?